# Problema com navbar bootstrap 3

Tags: css, bootstrap-3

Pessoa, boa noite! Eestou com problemas na estilização do icon-bar. Parte do código continha o form do search, então removi. E no search continha o **navbar-left** Com essa remoção quebrou parte do código, conforme imagem ao clicar no icon-bar ele fica a direita e não consigo jogar a esquerda.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
header.php

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">

          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="true">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          </div>


          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Principal <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>

              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Restaurante <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Adega</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Galeria de Fotos</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>

              <li><a href="#">O Cardápio</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Eventos</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>

            </ul>

          </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
```

Comment: Se vc colocar a classe **navbar-left** dentro da tag `ul` junto com as classes **nav** e **navbar-nav** é para funcionar.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/jh4c54 não funciona! eu já tinha colocado...

Comment: E com CSS, float:left ?

Comment: Também não! Mas, ela muda um pouco para a esquerda, quando eu coloco desta forma: <ul class="nav navbar navbar-nav navbar-left">

Comment: Já tentou pull-left, não sei qual Bootstrap está usando.

Comment: Não, funciona. Vou tentar refazer, ver se passei por algo errado, conseguindo eu retorno...

Comment: Funcionou! Acho que errei algo na codificação, refiz e deu certo. Solução resolvida, obrigado! http://prntscr.com/jh5yu3